# Is there a javascript's event listener equivalent to React's componentDidUpdate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, render, addeventlistener

I want to create a generic `<Tooltip />` component and be used from several other components. I want to use it like this:

```
<MyComponent ...props >
<Child1 />
...
<Tooltip />
...
</MyComponent>
```

When the `<Tooltip />` is rendered, I find the `parentNode` and attach to it some events like `mouseenter`, `mousemove` etc, but I also want to add event listeners that they will be triggered when the `componentDidUpdate` of the `MyComponent` will be triggered or at least as much close to this behavior.

For example, if `<Child1 />` changes it's width, it will cause a width change to `<MyComponent />` so I want to trigger an event listener to get the updated version of the `getBoundingClientRect()` of `<MyComponent />`.

In general I want these event listeners to be triggered on size change (width, height) or scroll position, so I will know where to exactly place the tooltip relative to the parent.

Maybe is a bad idea to have the `<Tooltip />` component as a child of the component I want to take effect on, instead of having it like :

```
<Tooltip>
<MyComponent ...props >
<Child1 />
...
...
</MyComponent>
</Tooltip>
```

but I find it way more convenient.

Comment: [mutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) will work, but it's closer to `componentDidUpdate`

Comment: @RandyCasburn But this won't work with scrolling and you will only see changes to `.style` but not what part of `.style` has been changed.

Comment: I missed scroll position, so both mutationObserver and [intersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/IntersectionObserver) for the scrolling bit.

Comment: @Andreas - reference the style bit. It is easy enough for the OP to put together a list (array) of properties to suck out of the `getComputedStyle()` of the mutated object and apply those styles directly to the secondary component.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I haven't said that it is not possible at all. Just that it is not possible to only look for changes in height/width of an element as you only "see" that `.style` has been changed but not what part of it exactly. You will have to do some manual work to find the exact changes and react to it - just as you've said.